# Error launching external scanner info generator (sh -c 'g++ -E -P -v -dD )

Tags: eclipse

```
Error launching external scanner info generator (sh -c 'g++ -E -P -v -dD )  

(Cannot run program "make": Launching failed)
```

More precisely, the error messages are:

```
Error Launching external scanner info generator - gcc link problem on MingGW

Error launching external scanner info generator (sh -c 'g++ -E -P -v -dD 
C:/Documents and Settings/user1/workspace123/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.make.core/specs.cpp ')

Error launching external scanner info generator (sh -c 'gcc -E -P -v -dD 
C:/Documents and Settings/user1/workspace123/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.make.core/specs.c ')
```

This problem is occurring  in eclipse-SDK-3.2.2-win32 with CDT.

Can anyone solve this problem?
Did anyone have any solution to this problem?
Please help to me to solve this problem .

Yours faithfully.
Anilkumar.k

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the problem where it couldn't find sh -- I removed the .lnk as suggested, but also changed the Compiler Invocation Command to c:\cygwin\bin\sh.exe

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to the recent version of Cygwin, as mentioned in [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.cdt/msg18401.html), also related to the [bug **218444**](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=218444)

> The real problem is that the `gcc.exe` (and `g++.exe`) is a symbolic link in
>   Cygwin; e.g.,

```
212008933@HCU-9YBF2G1 /bin
$ ls -l gcc*.*
-rwxr-x---+ 1 212008933 mkgroup-l-d 94741 Feb 25 04:14 gcc-3.exe
lrwxrwxrwx  1 212008933 mkgroup-l-d    21 Mar 16 14:50 gcc.exe ->
/etc/alternatives/gcc
```

> - I have found that the following procedure works for me:

1. delete `gcc.exe.lnk` and `g++.exe.lnk` from cygwin/bin
2. Copy `gcc-3.exe` to `gcc.exe`
3. Copy `g++-3.exe` to `g++.exe`

Answer (score 0):

Setting "Cygwin GCC" toolchain in project properties eliminated similar warning messages:

1. In Eclipse, right click on C++ project and select properties
2. Select C/C++ Build  >  Tool Chain Editor
3. Under "Current toolchain", select "Cygwin GCC"