# Error Launching external scanner info generator - gcc link problem on MingGW

Tags: mingw, eclipse-cdt

Error Launching external scanner info generator - gcc link problem on MingGW

Error launching external scanner info generator (sh -c 'g++ -E -P -v -dD C:/Documents and Settings/user1/workspace123/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.make.core/specs.cpp ')

Error launching external scanner info generator (sh -c 'gcc -E -P -v -dD C:/Documents and Settings/user1/workspace123/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.make.core/specs.c ')

this problem occuring  in eclipse-SDK-3.2.2-win32 -cdt
  can any one solve this problem .did any one have any solution to this problem .please help to me to solve this problem .
                                                           yours faithfully.
                                                           anilkumar

Comment: Please do not repeat your question and update/comment your original one (for which I have provided an answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914070/error-launching-external-scanner-info-generator-sh-c-g-e-p-v-dd

Answer (score 2):

Also had this error. Problem is g++/gcc (MinGW/bin) is not in the search path.
To correct do the following:

- Install MinGW
  (http://www.mingw.org/) if not installed yet.
- Add path
  to MinGW/bin (c:\MinGW\bin by
  default) to PATH environment
  variable.

This solved an error in my case.

Also make sure you're not using the restart command from eclipse. You'll need to shutdown Eclipse completely and then start it again for the change to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

I added c:\MinGW\bin to my Path, but I was still having a similar problem.

Setting "Cygwin GCC" toolchain in project properties eliminated my warning messages:

1. In Eclipse, right click on C++ project and select properties
2. Select C/C++ Build  >  Tool Chain Editor
3. Under "Current toolchain", select "Cygwin GCC"

Answer (score 0):

I'm presently trying to resolve this issue for myself, however on a Mac and with AVR-GCC on Eclipse... in my search I found this answer which seems more applicable to you than to me:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tips/CPP_Dev_eclipse_CDT.aspx

It speaks specifically to Win32 and there are examples more similar to your error...

Best of luck.