# No binary found Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse

The problem:

```
No includes folder in the project folder.  
Error: "Launch failed. Binaries not found"
```

I'm writing my first C code on Eclipse (new to Eclipse) but cant seem to run it. When I create a new project like so `file->new->c project-> choose empty project` and MinGW in toolchains and finish.

There I end up with a empty folder and no include  folder. From there i create a new src folder and a .cpp file, then i "build all" the code first then run it. After all that i end up with `Launch failed. Binaries not found`. I also checked that PE Windows Parser is on. Also this line is underlined red:

```
 #include <iostream>
```

What am i missing ?

Comment: Did you enable the correct binary parser in Project properties->C/C++ Build (PE for windows, ELF for Linux, mach for mac)?

Comment: It seems the compilation failed, due to missing include folders, and though no binary had been produced, so it can not be found.

Comment: You do have MinGW installed, don't you?

Comment: I think MinGQ is installed correctly, since i can selected in the toolchains. I downloaded eclipse C++ version and i just open it directly from download folder, that shouldnt be issue right ? what dont understand is why dont the include folder ?

Comment: Yes PE for windows is selected...

Comment: I just saw that in Project properties->C/C++ Build/Settings where I choose PE for windwos. It says "The configuration support is not installed on the system". Does that mean i have to install PE for windows in other ways ?

Comment: It says "The configuration support is not installed on the system" in properties-> toolchain editor even though MinGW is selected as current toolchain.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [this thread](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/719025/):

> If the toolchains show up in "`Create C++ project of selected type`", then Eclipse has detected them correctly.
>   The message "`Launch failed,binaries not found`" means that Eclipse cannot find the application you want to debug/launch! Most of the times this message appears when you forget to build your project before launching or build errors occurred. This can be compiler errors in your code or a missing/wrongly installed toolchain.

So, when you build "`hello world`",  check the output visible in the Console Window in Eclipse.

If the build fails because of:

```
Error launching external scanner info generator (gcc -E -P -v -dD)
```

, then see "[Error Launching external scanner info generator - gcc link problem on MingGW](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6256909/6309)".

Comment: I do press build, "Project ->Build All.  but it results in an error: Error launching external scanner info generator (gcc -E -P -v -dD )

Comment: @TommySolheim also, if you are using cygwin, http://stackoverflow.com/a/12015499/6309 could help.

Comment: ****  Attempting to build...  **** 


(Cannot run program "make" (in directory "F:\SSD\Documents\test"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: Okey i will check that link, thanks. didnt know i have to install MinGW separately.

Comment: Still wont work, i added MinGW and added that to my path on my computer. I get the include folder now at least, which directs to where MinGW is stored. But still binary not found error on run, after build, so frustrating.

Comment: @TommySolheim then double check with http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Fgetting_started%2Fcdt_w_basic.htm